# How can I transparently cache any directory or mounted file system for reads and write back?

Tags: cache, fuse, cloud

Say I mount some cloud storage (Amazon Cloud Drive in my case) with a FUSE client at `/mnt/cloud`. But because reading and writing files directly to `/mnt/cloud` is slow because it has to go over the internet, I want to cache the files that I'm reading from and writing to cloud storage. Since I might be writing a lot of data at a time, the cache should sit on my disk and not in RAM. But I don't want to replicate the entire cloud storage on my disk, because my disk may be too small.

So I want to have a cached view into `/mnt/cloud` mounted at `/mnt/cloud_cache`, which uses another path, say `/var/cache/cloud` as the caching location.

If I now read `/mnt/cloud_cache/file`, I want the following to happen:

Check whether `file` is cached at `/var/cache/cloud/file`.

1. If cached: Check `file` in cache is up-to-date by fetching modtime and/or checksum from `/mnt/cloud`. If it's up-to-date, serve the file from the cache, otherwise go to 2.
2. If not cached or cache is out-of-date: Copy `/mnt/cloud/file` to `/var/cache/cloud/file` and serve it from the cache.

When I write to `/mnt/cloud_cache/file`, I want this to happen:

1. Write to `/var/cache/cloud/file` and record in a journal that `file` needs to be written back to `/mnt/cloud`
2. Wait for writing to `/var/cache/cloud/file` to be done and/or previous write backs to `/mnt/cloud` to be completed
3. Copy `/var/cache/cloud/file` to `/mnt/cloud`

I have the following requirements and constraints:

- Free and open source
- Ability to set cache an arbitrary cache location
- Ability to cache an arbitrary location (probably some FUSE mount point)
- Transparent caching, i.e. using `/mnt/cloud_cache` is transparent to the caching mechanism and works like any other mounted file system
- Keeping a record of what needs to be written back (the cache might get a lot of data that needs to be written back to the original storage location over the course of days)
- Automatic deletion of cached files that have been written back or have not been accessed in a while
- Consistency (i.e. reflecting external changes to `/mnt/cloud`) isn't terribly important, as I will probably have only one client accessing `/mnt/cloud` at a time, but it would be nice to have.

I've spent quite some time looking for existing solutions, but haven't found anything satisfactory.

- FS-Cache and CacheFS (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/caching/fscache.txt) seems to only work with `nfs` or `afs` file systems and I don't know how to make it cache another FUSE file system or any general directory.
- bcache (https://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/) seems to only work with block devices, i.e. couldn't cache another FUSE file system
- gcsfuse (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse) I think this does exactly what I want, but it's integrated with Google Cloud Storage. To make it work in general, I would have to hack it and change any accesses to GCS to local file accesses in the given mount-point or accesses to Amazon Cloud Drive

Comment: Curious if you ever found a solution? Looking for a similar cache'ing layer with similar requires as your own.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/nikratio/s3ql/ does pretty much what I want. However, unfortunately, it doesn't play too nicely with Amazon Cloud Drive in particular (mainly ACD's fault by lack of a good Linux client)

Comment: I've used s3ql in the past myself, but having migrated over to ACD for my files seemed to limit it's use with that provider. Did run into problems with data consistency with s3ql when data collections > 2TB.

RClone seems promising but missing that vital caching piece.

Comment: If you are seriously interested in that - we can write it in C++, using tmpfs and stat.

Answer (score 9):

Try using [catfs](https://github.com/kahing/catfs/), a generic fuse caching filesystem I'm currently working on.

Comment: From what I'm seeing up to now it works like a charm.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: How is this different to the NFS middle layer solution below?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to use FS-Cache/CacheFS to cache a fuse-mounted system, by adding an NFS indirection inbetween: If your fuse mount is on /fusefs, then share it to yourself on nfs by writing this in /etc/exportfs:

`/fusefs localhost(fsid=0)`

Now you can do this:

`mount -t nfs -o fsc localhost:/fusefs /nfs
systemctl start cachefilesd`

and /nfs will offer cached access to /fusefs.

I'm using this approach with sshfs as the back FS, it works nicely.

(Unfortunately, this only speeds up access of file contents; file metadata is not cached so `stat` and `open` are still slow).

Comment: What if sshfs connection fails?  Wouldn't the nfs folder be treated as an empty folder and delete all files in the cached folder?

Comment: Does FS-Cache/CacheFS provide _write_ cache?

Answer (score 1):

This is an ignorant sort of answer, since I haven't access to an Amazon cloud directory with which to test it.  But in the ["How to Do It"](http://www.montypython.net/scripts/howtodoit.php?) spirit:  setup [Amazon cloud to serve NFS](http://hunterford.me/amazon-ec2-and-nfs/), then [login remotely to that NFS server using `cachefilesd`](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-enable-local-file-caching-for-nfs-share-on-linux.html).

<sub>"Easier said than done..."</sub>

Comment: Nice idea, but the question asks for a general solution that will work with other could storage providers (which I'm also looking for).